# Css translate 50% on odd width/height blurring background image

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, blurry

I'm working on a a div which has odd `width/height` and I need to transform it 50%, this blurs out my background image. Is there a way to fix it?

I have tryed to:

- `scale(2)` and `zoom(.5)`, but this gives me an issue when i move the component.
- `backface-visibility: hidden;` or `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;`, but this only fixes the text inside the div if it is blurry.
- `filter: blur(0)`
- Using tricks like `perspective(1)` or removing a single pixel from width/height would be a hack more than a solution.

```
<div class="my-div any-other-random-class"/>

// CSS
.myclass {
   transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}

.any-other-random-class{
   width: 123px;
   height: 111px;
}
```

I expect the background image not to be blurry, but it is blurry due to `translate` calculating a decimal value.

Edit: I have noticed this appening only on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
 transform: translateZ(0) translate(50%, 50%);
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-filter: blur(0);
 filter: blur(0);
```

Comment: nope, would work with text, but doesn't with background image on chrome.